# VIM: how to send entire line to a buffer of type "Terminal"?

Tags: bash, terminal

In Vim 8, you can open a terminal inside Vim with the `term` command. This opens a new buffer of type `terminal` inside vim. Is there any way of sending lines from other buffers to this type of buffer?

For example:

```
nmap <some binding> <sends the entire line under cursor to buffer of type='terminal'>
```

What I am trying to achieve with this is to evaluate REPL statements without using any plugins

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: you can do `:. term` to sent current line as input to terminal to execute/evaluate.

Comment: Have you tried [`term_sendkeys()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#term_sendkeys%28%29)?

Answer (score 10):

**Here is a solution using Vim's term_sendkeys()**

- open a vim terminal and start the REPL
  check which buffer the terminal is in with `:ls`
  this example assumes the terminal is in buffer 2
- cmd to copy the content to the " register (the unamed register) and paste/run in the terminal
  `:%y | call term_sendkeys(2, @")`

The command can then be mapped like this example:
`nnoremap <leader>sk :%y \| :call term_sendkeys(2, @")<CR>`

---

**Plugin Options:**
**There are also many plugins available.**

This one is the next step up from manual steps.
I've tried it and it works and was updated in September of 2020.

- https://github.com/KKPMW/vim-sendtowindow

Also, its README includes an extensive list of related plugins. A few of these have continued to be updated in 2021.

- https://github.com/KKPMW/vim-sendtowindow#see-also

---

**For those interested, here is a more manual solution**
Copy content into a register from an editing window and paste into the :terminal window with `<CTRL-W> " {reg}` to run it.

Example with one editing buffer and one :terminal buffer running bash:

- text content in editing window
  echo hello
- cmd to copy the content to the 0 register
  `:vipy`
- move to the terminal window
  `<CTRL-W> W`
- paste 0 register into terminal window
  `<CTRL-W> "0`
- :terminal output
  `hello`
- move back to editing window
  `<CTRL-W> W`

... continue editing...

This also works for python REPL and probably for other languages' REPLs.

Answer (score 5):

As Luc Hermitte pointed out, you can use `:h term_sendkeys` to send commands to terminal buffer, the hard part is to manage the terminal buffer:

```
function s:exec_on_term(lnum1, lnum2)
  " get terminal buffer
  let g:terminal_buffer = get(g:, 'terminal_buffer', -1)
  " open new terminal if it doesn't exist
  if g:terminal_buffer == -1 || !bufexists(g:terminal_buffer)
    terminal
    let g:terminal_buffer = bufnr('')
    wincmd p
  " split a new window if terminal buffer hidden
  elseif bufwinnr(g:terminal_buffer) == -1
    exec 'sbuffer ' . g:terminal_buffer
    wincmd p
  endif
  " join lines with "\<cr>", note the extra "\<cr>" for last line
  " send joined lines to terminal.
  call term_sendkeys(g:terminal_buffer,
        \ join(getline(a:lnum1, a:lnum2), "\<cr>") . "\<cr>")
endfunction

command! -range ExecOnTerm call s:exec_on_term(<line1>, <line2>)
nnoremap <leader>ex :ExecOnTerm<cr>
vnoremap <leader>ex :ExecOnTerm<cr>
```

read comment as explanation

**usage**

execute single line in normal mode, multiple lines in visual mode.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to send lines from a buffer into an open vim terminal, and this seemed like a possible solution:

```vim
" \tt will open a new terminal window
nnoremap <leader>tt :botright terminal<CR>

" \tr will send text to the window
nnoremap <leader>tr yy \| :call term_sendkeys(term_list()[0], @")<CR>
vnoremap <leader>tr y \| :call term_sendkeys(term_list()[0], @")<CR>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

```
:call term_list()[0]->term_sendkeys(getline('.') .. "\<CR>")
```

After sending first line, do, `@:` to repeat for next and then `@@` for rest.
Can be mapped to binding or user command if used frequently.