# Vi shortcut to execute line under cursor as a command

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I am searching for a way to execute a line under the cursor as a command. I assign it to a combination of `<Leader>el` and basically I found a way to do it with `:exe !@u` but the issue I have here is that special chars like # and % get expanded by vi as well. And I want the entire string in the named register to be executed literally as is. 
I tried with `:call system(@u)` but to no avail. 
Can you please help?

Comment: Vi or Vim? I think you mean `:exe '!'.@u` .  What if you change `:call system(@u)` to `echo system(@u)`. Might be related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14300/vim-how-to-send-entire-line-to-a-buffer-of-type-terminal .

Comment: Seconded: vi or vim? I have a mapping for this in my vim filetype settings: `nnoremap ... :execute getline('.')<CR>` to execute vimscript. `system` does something different.

Comment: Depends on what you want to run.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble it’s vim. Either way, I already tried with `:exe`. It didn’t work for me. Perhaps your vim is compiled or configured differently than mine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment of @dedowsdi, `echo system(@u)` worked. This is the answer. Unfortunately I cannot even upvote your comment. But you get the credit! Thank you so much!!